# ElasticSearch - single hit into multiple buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, business-intelligence

Lets say i have a **single** elasticsearch entry with two date fields - t0 and t1.
lets say those t0 and t1 are "2017-10-18T09:00:00" and "2017-10-18T12:00:00" - as in the same date, different hours (for simplicity's sake)

I would like to perform an aggregation query that will give me a bucket hit in every hour - as in, the hourly range is 09:00-12:00, and i would like to get 3 buckets - one for each hour in the range, with a hit in each - for instance:
if were talking about the same range of 09:00-12:00 then i would want that same entry to be counted in the following buckets:
09:00-10:00
10:00-11:00
11:00-12:00

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I inserted 4 documents with dates as :: 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 11:30

```
{
"size": 0, 
"aggs" : {
    "buckets" : {
        "date_histogram" : {
            "field" : "date",
            "interval" : "1h",
            "format" : "HH:mm" 
        }
    }
}
}
```

This will return a result as follows.

```
"aggregations": {
  "buckets": {
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key_as_string": "09:00",
           "key": 1508317200000,
           "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
           "key_as_string": "10:00",
           "key": 1508320800000,
           "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
           "key_as_string": "11:00",
           "key": 1508324400000,
           "doc_count": 2
        }
     ]
  }
  }
```

I guess this is want you need.

Comment: Hey swap. substitute the '4' documents, with '1' document having 2 date fields - first with 09:00, second with 11:30 - but result bucket should be the same

Comment: I think its not possible then.